# Receiving responses to responses from messages broadcast to 255.255.255.255 on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, networking, udp

I am sending broadcast to zero network [255.255.255.255] (e.g. DHCP or any other specific protocol, which **cannot use** any specific broadcast address and limited to local only) from the specific interface and expecting to get response.
So as part as result of Bind() for dgram callback, i am trying to add my local ip to this broadcast group

```
socket.setMulticastTTL(128);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
socket.addMembership(BROAD_ADDRESS,ip);
socket.setMulticastLoopback(true);
```

and getting error.

> throw errnoException(err, 'addMembership');
>     ^
>
> Error: addMembership EINVAL

I would assume, that since this is local address it is already a part of zero network group (like in Windows). But the problem is that without using addMembership call, i can see response traffic coming to the interface, but NodeJS client is not able to receive it.

Everything works fine (i am able to send messages and get responses, when using any other broadcast address), but not this specific one.
This also not works with network specific addresses (e.g. for 10.1.10.0/24 network with broadcast to 10.1.10.255)

*So, how to receive responses to broadcast messages to zero network on linux?*

Comment: The Limited Broadcast address (`255.255.255.255`) is _not_ a multicast address, so you cannot subscribe to it the way you do with a multicast address. I'm not sure what you mean by it being a zero network address. The Limited Broadcast address is defined by RFCs 919 and 922.

Comment: Zero network (255.255.255.255) by RFC is basically broadcast to all available networks. Obviously i can  subscribe to it. No problem at all. The issue that i am facing is that since this group by definition should include all address on all available networks, you should not be able to addMembership to this address. And this is why this error message is coming.

Comment: "_Zero network (255.255.255.255) by RFC is basically broadcast to all available networks._" No, it's only for the network on which it is sent. It specifically says so in the RFCs. I don't know where you came up with the term, "zero network." That is the Limited Broadcast address, and it cannot cross a layer-3 device. It is _not_ a multicast group. You seem to be very confused. The multicast groups are in the `224.0.0.0/4` network. If anything, the Limited Broadcast belongs to the Reserved addresses (`240.0.0.0/4`), which cannot be used for anything.

Comment: "A special definition exists for the IP broadcast address 255.255.255.255. It is the broadcast address of the zero network or 0.0.0.0, which in Internet Protocol standards stands for this network". But, again, this is not really related to the question. I understand that it is normal not to be able to add my local ip to this group, since, this ip is already added (since it is local network). But having said that, i still should be able to receive messages, sent to this address from any local endpoint, regardless on ip i am listening on, assuming it is on the same network.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that quote, but it doesn't match the RFCs, which are the IP definitions. The `0.0.0.0/8` network is called "This Network". Trying to use multicast for non-multicast addresses is crazy, and you are getting an error, as you should. A host receiving packets destined to the `255.255.255.255` Limited Broadcast address is supposed to process those packets. If you host does not, then it is non-compliant with the standards.